# Using URI that contains underscore with Camel HTTP4

Tags: http, apache-camel, uri, apache-httpclient-4.x

We are trying to use `Apache Camel` 2.16.3 to push some data to a third-party `HTTP` endpoint. We are using `HTTP4` Component. We are setting the uri, method and query params as headers in the message. However, the endpoint contains an underscore (`_`) and we are getting an exception like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: https://x_y.something.com/somePath?q_one=XXXX&q_two=YYYYY. If you are forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint: Endpoint[https4://placeholder?throwExceptionOnFailure=false]

I have been researching a bit and it looks like that `_` is something that should not be there in the URI. This [website](http://formvalidation.io/validators/uri/) actually says that `https://x_y.something.com/somePath` is invalid but `https://xy.something.com/somePath` is valid.

Since I cannot change the third-party endpoint, is it possible to escape the underscore somehow? If not, is there any other solution or we need to abandon `Apache Camel` for this?

Comment: can you please share camel route that you created. I think if you add `&bridgeEndpoint=true` then it should start work

Comment: That would not work because I am setting the `URI` in the headers with `Exchange.HTTP_URI`. The endpoint does not have a valid `URI`. Also, I don't have a `route`, I am using an `akka-camel` producer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
Without seeing a code example I cannot be sure what the root cause is, but if I understand correctly, you are sending an HTTP request to an akka actor which is consuming from a Camel endpoint. My guess is that you're probably not populating the headers correctly - regardless of what the original `HTTP4` endpoint looks like, `Exchange.HTTP_URI` header override will always take precedence. For example, this works perfectly fine:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:9090/path")
    .routeId("jetty_server")
    .log("${body}");

from("timer:sender?delay=3000&period=5000")
    .setBody().constant("Ping!")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, constant("http://localhost:9090/path"))
    .to("http4:x_y.something.com:9090/path?q_one=XXXX&q_two=YYYYY");
```

So my guess is that it's not a Camel issue.

Comment: I tried but it did not fix the issue. It seems the issue is more a standard thing than anything else... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Comment: Can you share some details then on how the actors are starting and which endpoint URI they are using? And if you're the one setting the URI, then why don't you use the proper URI? Where are the actors hosted?

Comment: Can you confirm that it would work if the route is like this? `from("timer:sender?delay=3000&period=5000")
    .setBody().constant("Ping!")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, constant("https://x_y.something.com:9090/path"))
    .to("https4:something.com:9090/path?q_one=XXXX&q_two=YYYYY");`

Comment: Well, no, because the header overrides the URI in the http4 endpoint. Which parameter can you change?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I'll leave this here to help future users.

Having had this exact issue before, I can tell you that the underscore is the likely culprit here. You'll probably find that if you remove the underscore, while your service will (obviously) fail to contact the endpoint, it should interpret the URI correctly. However, if the error persists you may also have to add the bridgeEndpoint option too.

Unfortunately, I never found a handy way to get around this limitation when using Camel. One idea I toyed with was creating a custom Camel Processor to handle the URI connection.

Ultimately, my working solution was to stand up a second bit of infrastructure; a gateway proxy, whose hostname we could control and ensure conformed to standards. We set up an endpoint on our gateway that proxied to the bad endpoint. We then configured our service to contact the gateway's endpoint instead, and sure enough it worked.